# Is there any ways to earn money from flights with PPL license?

Tags: ppl, malaysia, indonesia, thailand

I want to apply a flight school to get flight license (in Thailand), but I have not enough money to pay for CPL training at once.
Is there any legal ways to earn money from flights with PPL in South-East Asia?
Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Not sure putting your flying on youtube is considered commercial or not. Other than that I doubt Thai CAAT would pursue license action as long as you don’t crash or make other people report you.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. In my case, YouTube blogging isn't the best option, but it could be useful if I couldn't find anything else.

Comment: Do you have a skillset that can be used to earn remotely, like software development? Career change is usually more comfortable with the old job for finances. Doubly so for jobs that double as pleasure, so have a lot of beginners competing for the entry level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called a PPL for a reason. PPL is for **Private** operations only. You may not act as pilot-in-command of an aeroplane for compensation or hire, nor an aircraft carrying passengers or property for compensation or hire. However, you may act as PIC of an aircraft and receive pro rata share, or an equal portion, of the operating expenses (fuel, oil, airport expenditures, and rental fees only) from others onboard the aircraft, as long as you do not pay less than the pro rata share. You can act as pilot-in-command of an aircraft towing a glider, fly for charity, non-profit, or community events, etc.

Edit: This **does not** apply for all countries, it varies greatly and you must check your laws and proceed with due discretion.

Comment: Thank you for explanation.

Comment: Note that the exceptions listed may not apply in every country.

Comment: Thank you for your remark. Of course, I'll check twice local flight laws before any operations.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer really, but something you will come up against is the insurance industry's view of your activities. Insurance policies for an aircraft for commercial use are going to entail a very different risk profile, and greater cost, to ones for personal use, and a personal insurance policy for you, a passenger or a client is going to be complicated by a series of legalities that insurance companies will use at every opportunity to refuse paying out a claim. They will not tolerate you making money out of you avoiding paying them.
Be aware of your liabilities in this respect. Things can and do go wrong, particularly to the inexperienced.

Comment: I really wonder how this answer is more complete than mine, it literally says "Not an answer". Mine was selected first why did it change?

Comment: Tapped wrong button after sleep.

Comment: ok sorry if I seemed rude, didn't mean to.