Can you pay a pilot to take you on a flight if you are the owner of the LSA?
Are you allowed to pay a pilot (whether a Sport Pilot or a Private Pilot PPL) to take you on a flight if you are the owner of the LSA aircraft the flight is being done?

This answer also answers your question: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/102240/66887

No. Unless one of a few exceptions apply, private pilots cannot be compensated for their services. In fact, they can't even fly you for free. Giving a private pilot free or discounted flight time in your plane is considered to be "compensation" by the FAA, and private pilots are not allowed to act as PIC for compensation or hire per 14 CFR 61.113(a):

Except as provided in paragraphs (b) through (h) of this section, no person who holds a private pilot certificate may [...], for compensation or hire, act as pilot in command of an aircraft

None of the exceptions are likely to apply here, but even if they do, a private pilot with passengers is required to pay at least a pro rata share of the expenses per 14 CFR 61.113(c):

A private pilot may not pay less than the pro rata share of the operating expenses of a flight with passengers, provided the expenses involve only fuel, oil, airport expenditures, or rental fees.

Meaning even if one of the exceptions apply, a private pilot has to pay for at least half (or 1/3 with 2 passengers, etc. But of course LSAs can only carry one passenger currently) the fuel, oil, and airport expenditures.
Sport pilots are totally forbidden from receiving compensation for acting as PIC and so even this cost sharing is not allowed.
Paying a commercial pilot to fly you in your own airplane is legal.

Ok, Can I also pay a comercial pilot to fly me in my airplane if the airplane is a LSA?

@Gabe Yes. If you pay someone else to fly you in your plane, the plane is not being operated for compensation or hire. So it being an LSA is irrelevant.

No
That would be a violation of 14 CFR 61.113:

(a) Except as provided in paragraphs (b) through (h) of this section, no person who holds a private pilot certificate may act as pilot in command of an aircraft that is carrying passengers or property for compensation or hire; nor may that person, for compensation or hire, act as pilot in command of an aircraft.

P.S.  This topic has been beat to death all over the internet, please do some basic research before posting a question.

Small detail- the aircraft is not carrying passengers for compensation or hire. So it's actually the next clause "nor may that person, for compensation or hire, act as pilot in command of an aircraft" that actually forbids the described operation. These separately forbid a private pilot from acting as PIC (even for free) when the operator is being compensated (first clause) and from receiving compensation themselves (second clause).

@Chris, good point, thanks!  Made an edit above...

@Chris, is that downvote yours by chance?  Because I acknowledged your point and fixed it...

It is not. Honestly my point was pedantic enough I don't think it would be worthy of a downvote even if you refused to fix it. ;)
